# Unable to update ng-apexcharts dynamically

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I need help with updating my apex boxplot when the underlying data gets updated. In the chart component below, the `updateBoxSeries` gets triggered by a form component when the submit button gets clicked. However, this simple update fails to be executed (template does not update), despite the documentation saying that the update event gets triggered when the chart property gets changed.

I suspect that it has to do with the component being unable to find the ref selector in `updateBoxSeries`, as it complains about `this.chart` being undefined, if I were to try updating the chart properties directly instead of updating via chartOptions. Please note that while updating via this.chartOptions does not result in complaints, it doesn't update the template.

**chart.component.ts**

```
export class MyChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("updatableChart", {static: true}) chart: ChartComponent;
  public chartOptions: Partial<ChartOptions>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.chart works fine over here
    this.chart.series[0]['data'] = [
      {
        x: new Date('2021-05-31').getTime(),
        y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      }
    ];
  }

  constructor(private natwage: CompareMyWageDataService) {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [{
        name: 'box',
        type: 'boxPlot',
        data: [
          {
            x: new Date('2021-05-31').getTime(),
            y: []
          }
        ]
      }],
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "boxPlot"
      },
      colors: ['#008FFB', '#FEB019'],
      title: {
        text: 'BoxPlot - Scatter Chart',
        align: 'left'
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function(val) {
            return new Date(val).getFullYear().toLocaleString()
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        intersect: true
      }
    };
  }

  public updateBoxSeries(): void {
    this.chartOptions.series[0]['data'] = [
      {
        x: new Date('2021-05-31').getTime(),
        y: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
      }
    ];

    // This block gets complained about this.chart being undefined
    this.chart.series[0]['data'] = [
      {
        x: new Date('2021-05-31').getTime(),
        y: [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
      }
    ];
  }
```

**chart.component.html**

```
<apx-chart #updatableChart
  [series]="chartOptions.series"
  [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
  [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
  [title]="chartOptions.title"
  [colors]="chartOptions.colors"
  [tooltip]="chartOptions.tooltip"
></apx-chart>
```